# How to create a Web App to Reset a Password for Azure AD Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am a Graph API newb that is trying to create a web app, for Self-Service Password Reset, to reset an Azure AD account password to the user-specified password via a simple form.  My thought was to require Azure MFA when accessing the app using phone, SMS or Microsoft Authenticator app to validate the user's identity, then present the user with a New Password and Confirm New Password box (web app).

1. Is the above possible?
2. If not possible, how could I accomplish this without the user knowing their current password?

Working with the Graph API is new to me, so be gentle :).

**Background:** We have a SSO client on each Windows 7 and Windows 10 PC in our environment.  This loads it's own credential provider with a "Forgot Password?" link that can be configured to point to a third party SSPR URL.  Instead of using their SSPR solution (which costs $$$), we've chosen to create our own.  The web app would be accessed BEFORE a user logs into his/her workstation, from the Windows login screen.

Comment: you can reset password using Graph API. Here are the steps need to follow.
1. Registere you web app with AD with proper permisiions such as read/write user details.. with MFA 
2.  use the Graph API to reset. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword

I can say it is possible

Comment: Use this one instead https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/passwordprofile . Azure AD provided above by @BapaiahMalasani has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  Can you point me towards a sample of the above?

Comment: Both AAD Graph API and Microsoft Graph  can be used. Microsoft Graph is not supported by Microsoft currently.

Comment: Since the AAD graph seems to be on the way out, I will attempt this with the Microsoft Graph unless the below article is false.  https://redmondmag.com/articles/2017/05/11/azure-active-directory-graph-deprecation.aspx

Comment: Reset Password is an Unsupported end-user operation, using  Graph API